# Problems with the library

Tags: flutter, dart, import, compiler-errors, fatal-error

I am working on my app and since a few days I cannot compile my code anymore. Do you have an idea why all the library are red and how I can fix this?

Thank you so much for your expertise and hope to hear from you soon.

Thanks

Martin

[image]

Comment: run flutter doctor command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `flutter clean` & then run `flutter pub get`

Comment: Thanks for the nice help. I was doing this and than under Preferences --> Dart --> DART SDK and I pressed Apply again and it solved the Problem. Thank you so much :)